# Robotium: Click on text in the alertDialog only, not in the underneath activity

Tags: android, robotium

I have an activity displaying some text, for example "someText".

**From this activity, I open an alert dialog box as follow:**

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
builder.setTitle("Title");
String[] items = {"Hello", "World", "someText"};
builder.setItems(items, new MultiChoiceEventOnClickListener(...);
builder.setCancelable(true);
builder.show();
```

**And here is my Robotium test:**

```
solo.clickOnButton(...); // to open the dialog alert
solo.waitForDialogToOpen();
solo.clickOnText("someText");
```

The problem is that **Robotium** finds the text in the activity under the alert dialog.
As "someText" can be anywhere in my activity, I cannot use an index.

How can I narrow the search of the text to the `alertDialog` only?
or 
How can I find the view item in the list of items in the alert dialog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be possible to search for the text manually like that:

```
ArrayList<View> views = solo.getCurrentViews();
for(View v : views) {
   if (!v instanceof TextView) {
      //filter out everything thats not a TextView
      continue;
   }

   String text = ((TextView)v).getText().toString();
   if (text.contains("sometext") {
      //We found the view, click and then exit the loop. 
      solo.clickOnView(v);
      break;
   }
}
```

Disclaimer: As I currently don't have an Android environment set up on my machine I couldn't verify it

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I expected something integrated in Robotium existed.
Note: In your code proposal, I will also need to check that the parent is the AlertDialog box

Comment: I would expect that this is not necessary, according to the docs: 
`getCurrentViews()

    Returns an ArrayList of the Views currently displayed in the focused Activity or Dialog.`

Comment: Maybe the doc is not correct. When I call `getCurrentViews()`, all the views of the AlertDialog box AND the activity under it are returned. Hence this post.